# how to show dynamic textview in android using sax parser?

Tags: android, xml, saxparser

Hi I created one grid view application. it's display my sdcard images in my grid view, now I have 10 images only. if I click my 1st image in grid view I want to show one paragraph using text view. then i click 2nd images i want to show another one paragraph....so i create one xml file, the xml file have 10 paragraph. my doubt how to show this paragraph? when i click that gridview images i wish to show this images that's all....

```
<paragraph>

<par1>
dkdkkddkdkkdkkdkdkkdkdkdkdkdkdkdk]
dkdkkdkdkdkdkkdkdkdkdkdkdkdkdk
</par1>

<par2>
skjdkjfidfdjfkdjfoiudifjieiiejriej
dkiekdikdididkdkdkipppw;wpp;eokkll
</par2>
.
.
.
.
.
<par10>
dkdi;;iathehe thid tihoodfjalkjfkjdfk
dkjfldkjflkjdalkjldkjoaiuidfiudofuoia
</par10>
</paragraph>
```

This is my example xml file i wish to parse only sax parse only. I am confused please help me........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your xml structure as below:

```
<paragraph>

<par> dkdkkddkdkkdkkdkdkkdkdkdkdkdkdkdk] dkdkkdkdkdkdkkdkdkdkdkdkdkdkdk </par>

<par> skjdkjfidfdjfkdjfoiudifjieiiejriej dkiekdikdididkdkdkipppw;wpp;eokkll </par> . . . . . <par> dkdi;;iathehe thid tihoodfjalkjfkjdfk dkjfldkjflkjdalkjldkjoaiuidfiudofuoia </par> </paragraph>
```

Then Parse these strings into an arraylist, and according to the selection position of image, display paragraph from index.

Answer (score 2):

First of all you have to parse your xml  and store all the paragraph data into array or arralist.

Write the onItemclickListener event of Gridview  and display the Custom dialog in grid's onItemClickListener.

In Custom dialog, you have to set one xml file with textview.

Also, you have to set the value  of that TextView in onItemclickListener.

You have to get the data with the help of the the index argument of the listener.

```
gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            //get the data for textView by passing index in  para[index]
            //use the custom dialog  to show the your paragraph
        }
    });
```